# Selenuim webdriver trying to automate a click linkbutton?

Tags: button, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selennium Webdriver to automate a click of a PDF download button. I used various ways to click the button, but it seems to throw a Jscript error:

```
Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 17
Char: 29094
Code: 0
URI: http://uat.mysite.com/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
```

My click code (tried these both):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(text(), 'Download PDF')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='paginationWrap']/a[@class='redBlock']")).click();
```

The html:

```
<div class='articleFoot'>
    <div class='paginationWrap'>
        <a class='redBlock' target="_blank" href='/DownloadMedia.aspx?media={625B459D-C085-48C5-931C-71BE03786236}'>
            Download PDF
            <span class='icon pdf'></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these xpath expressions are ok.

If the exception is really *not* from the jquery script (is it not?), then it's most likely that Selenium can't really download files. Yet.

Still, besides the HtmlUnitDriver (whose behaviour I don't know), the browser should offer you a download dialog. Try another Driver, then look for errors elsewhere.

You can do some tricks to achieve a file download alternatively, my personal favourite is [this downloader](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java), but there are a few more ways like getting and setting up [Download Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/) into Firefox, some [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) moves and so on. But do you really need to?

Comment: You are right the issue is with Selenuim, deos not handle download dialogs. Needed to use a 3rd party tool. One solution is http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html#comment-form.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
WebElement state = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(text(), 'Download PDF')]"));
Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
builder1.moveToElement(state).click().perform();
```